# Write integration test case for grails plugins

Tags: grails, testing, integration-testing, grails-plugin, spock

I am implementing a plugin there i have service.

```
class PersonalEquipmentRateService {

    List<PersonalEquipmentRate> findActiveByDate(Date date){
        List<PersonalEquipmentRate> personalEquipmentRateList = PersonalEquipmentRate.createCriteria().list {
            and {
                ge 'effectiveDate', date
                le 'expiryDate', date
            }
        }
        return personalEquipmentRateList
    }

}
```

I have write test cases for domain those working fine.But while i am writing test cases for services I am getting following error .

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method on class [PersonalEquipment] was used outside of a Grails application. If running in the context of a test using the mocking API or bootstrap Grails correctly.
```

My test case code is :-

```
class PersonalEquipmentRateServiceSpec extends IntegrationSpec {

    def personalEquipmentRateService

    def setup() {
    }

    def cleanup() {
    }

    void "test personalEquipmentRateService"() {
        when:
        PersonalEquipment personalEquipment= new PersonalEquipment(ownerId:1,assetId:1,unitNumber:"UNO",hourlyRate:1,dailyRate:100,dayRateHours:12,businessUnitId:12,personalEquipmentRate:null,dateCreated:new Date(),lastUpdated:new Date(),siteId:12)
        personalEquipment.save(failOnError: true,flush:true)
        PersonalEquipmentRate personalEquipmentRate=new PersonalEquipmentRate(rate:100.0,effectiveDate:getDate('06/05/2014'),expiryDate:getDate('16/12/2014'),dateCreated:new Date(),lastUpdated:new Date(),personalEquipment:personalEquipment,uomId:1)
        personalEquipmentRate.save(failOnError: true,flush:true)
        List<PersonalEquipmentRate> personalEquipmentRateList=personalEquipmentRateService.findActiveByDate(getDate('06/05/2014'))

        then:
        assert true
        1==personalEquipmentRateList.size()

    }
    private Date getDate(String dateString) {
        return new Date().parse("d/M/yyyy", dateString)
    }

}
```

Suggest me some solution.

My Build.config 
grails.project.class.dir = "target/classes"

```
grails.project.test.class.dir = "target/test-classes"
grails.project.test.reports.dir = "target/test-reports"

grails.project.fork = [
    // configure settings for compilation JVM, note that if you alter the Groovy version forked compilation is required
    //  compile: [maxMemory: 256, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, daemon:true],

    // configure settings for the test-app JVM, uses the daemon by default
    test: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, daemon:true],
    // configure settings for the run-app JVM
    run: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false],
    // configure settings for the run-war JVM
    war: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false],
    // configure settings for the Console UI JVM
    console: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256]
]

grails.project.dependency.resolver = "maven" // or ivy
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    // inherit Grails' default dependencies
    inherits("global") {
        // uncomment to disable ehcache
        // excludes 'ehcache'
    }
    log "warn" // log level of Ivy resolver, either 'error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug' or 'verbose'
    repositories {
        grailsCentral()
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        // uncomment the below to enable remote dependency resolution
        // from public Maven repositories
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org"
        //mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/"
    }
    dependencies {
        // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes eg.
        // runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.27'
    }

    plugins {
        build(":release:3.0.1",
              ":rest-client-builder:1.0.3") {
            export = false
        }
        compile (":hibernate:3.6.10.18")
    }
}
```

DataSource.config

```
dataSource {
    pooled = true
    jmxExport = true
    driverClassName = "org.h2.Driver"
    username = "sa"
    password = ""
}
hibernate {
    cache.use_second_level_cache = true
    cache.use_query_cache = false
    cache.region.factory_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory' // Hibernate 3
//    cache.region.factory_class = 'org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory' // Hibernate 4
    singleSession = true // configure OSIV singleSession mode
}

// environment specific settings
environments {
    development {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "create-drop" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
            url = "jdbc:h2:mem:devDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE"
        }
    }
    test {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:h2:mem:testDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE"
        }
    }
    production {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:h2:prodDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE"
            properties {
               // See http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#dataSource for documentation
               jmxEnabled = true
               initialSize = 5
               maxActive = 50
               minIdle = 5
               maxIdle = 25
               maxWait = 10000
               maxAge = 10 * 60000
               timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 5000
               minEvictableIdleTimeMillis = 60000
               validationQuery = "SELECT 1"
               validationQueryTimeout = 3
               validationInterval = 15000
               testOnBorrow = true
               testWhileIdle = true
               testOnReturn = false
               jdbcInterceptors = "ConnectionState"
               defaultTransactionIsolation = java.sql.Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that you don't have any database persistent engine i.e. either hibernate or mongodb. Make sure you have hibernate installed on your plugins's BuildConfig.groovy.

```
plugins {
    build(":release:3.0.1",
          ":rest-client-builder:1.0.3") {
        export = false
    }
    runtime ':hibernate:3.6.10.13'
    // Other dependencies
}
```

In general, whenever you ask any question, please specify your Grails version & some environments like jdk version etc.

Thanks,
SA

Comment: I am using h2 database.

Comment: Okay, Which version of grails are you using for plugin?

Comment: Can you please post your BuildConfig.groovy dependencies & DataSource.groovy config for test environment.

Comment: I added Build and DataSource config file .

Comment: @praveen_programmer Although you are using h2 database but you need to install the hibernate plugin for integration test case. I've updated the plugin version in my answer. Add it your BuildConfig.groovy and that will work.

Comment: This fixes the problem, but you're now exporting the hibernate plugin as a dependency. Change it to `runtime ':hibernate:3.6.10.13', { export = false }` so you use it locally for development, but don't leak it into installed apps.